# LibreOffice "automatic file name extension" box missing

Tags: libreoffice

I often create TSV files in LibreOffice Calc. The "automatic file name extension" box required for this process used to be an option when you `File > Save As`. It is no longer there since upgrading to LibreOffice 6. Where did it go? How do I get it back?

*screenshot below is not from my actual system, just a representation of the box that should be there*

[image]

Comment: Is this Ubuntu?

Comment: @George Udosen good question, that screen capture is not from my system, just updated the post explaining that. is only used to represent that box that went missing.

Comment: A Windows screenshot is no good here since file extensions are handled differently in Linux by convention. It would make sense for an application to offer different options in regards to them as needed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Something is screwed in the settings. I confirmed this on a separate fresh install. Anyway you need to change `UseSystemFileDialog` from `TRUE` to `FALSE`. If you create TSV files this is good to know.

The setting can be found at *Tools > Options > LibreOffice > Advanced > Open Expert Configuration* > `org.openoffice.Office.Common` > `UseSystemFileDialog` > `FALSE`.